# filter the_title problem in nav

Tags: filters, hooks

Hi I have a problem with the_title filter:

I have this code at my constructor:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', array($this, 'change_title') );
```

and this as callback (for testing purposes)

```
 public function change_title($title)
 {
    return 'title';                 
 }
```

But is filtering my navigation items!
instead of show home, pages, etc all changed to `'title'`
[image: screenshoot]

Any Ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the [`in_the_loop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) conditional to check if the context of `the_title` is within the loop.