# Change the_title() of a page dynamically

Tags: plugin-development, menus, pages, title

I'm developing a plugin that doesn't use a custom post type, but separate database tables.
It's a plugin that displays a list of courses with links that lead to the different course detail pages, where the user then can subscribe for a course.

In the current state, I'm using a shortcode to get the plugins data into a page with a custom page template (page-courses.php).

I now want to change `the_title()` dynamically, according to the page that the plugin shows (list of courses, course details page with forms, form submission success page). But whenever I do that with the following filter, the links to other pages in the footer also change:

```
<?php
 
add_filter('the_title', 'custom_page_title');
function custom_page_title() {
    return 'Custom Title';
}
```

### Edit

In the footer.php I have a function that includes footer links with `wp_nav_menu()` so I can define them in Appearance > Menus. But with the filter above, all the links in the footer also change to 'Custom Title'. But I just want to change the title of the page, not affecting menu links in the footer.

Trying to add a conditional tag `in_the_loop()` the footer links are still affected, although they are not in the loop.

```
<?php

add_action( 'loop_start', 'set_custom_title' );
function set_custom_title() {
    if ( in_the_loop() ) {
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_page_title' );
    }
}

function custom_page_title() {
    return 'Custom Title';
}
```

It’s similar to this question: [filter the_title problem in nav](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47270/filter-the-title-problem-in-nav), just that the links affected are in the footer and `in_the_loop()` doesn't work.

How I can I change `the_title()` while only affecting the title of the current page being shown *not affecting links in the footer*?

### Edit 2 - Solution

So I finally got it working:

```
<?php

add_action( 'loop_start', 'set_custom_title' );
function set_custom_title() {
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse83525_filter_the_title', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse83525_filter_the_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( 'page-listcourses.php' == get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        return 'Custom Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

The file page-listcourses.php is a Custom Post Template that I assigned to the static page named 'Courses'.

I assume it didn't work before because the name of the static page and filename of the Custom Post Template were the same.

Comment: Why are you rolling your own database tables? Your life would be much simpler if you implemented your **custom content** as a *Custom Post Type*.

Comment: I actually thought that this question would come. I develop this plugin to get to know Wordpress, so I first didn't know about Custom Post Types. I have two database tables, one for the courses and one for the course categories. One category can have several courses, so the two tables are linked. I don't think it's that easy to accomplish it with Custom Post Types. Sure I could use Custom Taxonomies for the courses, but I would have to add more fields, because a course category does not just have name. Just for now it's much easier to do it with custom database tables.

Comment: Your use case is the *exact, intended use case* for Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomies. You may be *misunderestimating* the elegance, flexibility, and power of CPTs and Custom Taxonomies.

Comment: It’s indeed possible that I do. I should probably just try. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `in_the_loop()` is set to `true` whenever `the_post()` is fired. Without digging too deeply into core, and knowing that nav menus are themselves *loops*, I'm guessing that somewhere along the way, `wp_nav_menu()` instantiates a loop, causing `in_the_loop()` to return `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the [**`is_page_template()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) conditional:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-courses.php' ) ) {
    // The current page uses your
    // custom page template;
    // do something
}
```

### Edit

You would use this conditional *inside* your filter callback:

```
function wpse83525_filter_the_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-courses.php' ) ) {
        return 'Custom Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse83525_filter_the_title' );
```

Now, to isolate only the titles of pages that use your page template, you can take advantage of the other parameter passed to `the_title`: `$id`. Since you know the Id of the post for which the title is being filtered, you can query the `_wp_page_template` post meta, and ensure that it equals your page template:

```
function wpse83525_filter_the_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( 'page-courses.php' == get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        return 'Custom Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse83525_filter_the_title', 10, 2 );
```

### Edit 2

If you want to target the "Courses" page specifically, use `is_page()` with the page slug `'courses'`, or the page title of `'Courses'`:

```
function wpse83525_filter_the_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page( 'Courses' ) ) {
        return 'Custom Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse83525_filter_the_title' );
```

Though, I would recommend changing `page-courses.php` into a **Custom Page Template**, which would make this whole process much more robust.

Comment: That didn't work for now. But I refined my question, because it might not have been specific enough. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean by "*that didn't work for now*"? What *exactly* did you try? What did you expect to happen, that didn't, or what happened unexpectedly?

Comment: See updated answer, that should address the nav menu item titles.

Comment: I said that because I think your answer might be the right one (pushing in the right direction), but that I maybe didn't ask my question clear enough. `get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', true )` returns `default` and I don't know what to do with this. When I set 'page-courses.php' to 'default', all the nav links change, except when I hook the `the_title` filter to `loop_start`, then only the footer links change. I checked which template file is used, and it's 'page-courses.php' and not 'page.php' (which I thought might be the default one).

Comment: So, is "Courses" the name of your static page?

Comment: Yes, that's the name of the static page.

Comment: See updated answer. You can target a page by its title or slug, using `is_page()`.

Comment: I got it working now. See first question post to see what I did. The file page-courses.php was always a Custom Page Template. I assume it didn't work before because the name of the static page and filename of the Custom Post Template were the same. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: For future reference: I recommend **not** naming custom page templates as `page-foobar.php`, for precisely this reason. I use `template-foobar.php` instead.

Answer (score 1):

While `is_page_template()` will work, I prefer to put this kind of code in the page template itself to have all the code that generates this kind of page in one file.

Comment: How would that work, under the assumption that the code in question uses `the_title()`? Code examples?

Comment: @ChipBennett, I don't understand the question. If he needs the filter to be applied only for page with a specific template then he can place the same code in the template before calling `get_header()`.

Comment: Yes, actually I too think this would work. However, I think I would have to take the detour to set a variable in the plugin that would be available in query_vars? So for me, filtering `the_title` is a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to edit the current page title, use the `in_the_loop()`conditional, as in:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'modify_onpage_title', 10, 2);

function modify_onpage_title( $title , $id = null ) {

    if(!in_the_loop()){
        // returns early if not relevant (as in custom menu loops)
        return $title;
    }

    // Tweak your title
    $title = "Yolo! ". $title;
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to ensure `the_title()` is only being modified on the pages that you want.